# Docker swarm - selenium VNC port - how to make it distinct?

Tags: selenium, docker, port, vnc, swarm

I'm coming from VMs background and with each having a different IP there's no issue connecting to a specific node in a group on a VNC port.

With containers, looking at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/README.md , "Version 3 with Swarm support"
I can see that I can publish a port for a service corresponding to a specific container image, but I think that'd be a single value for a number of replicas.
So, if I use, say, 20 containers and each container suffixed "debug" exposes VNC on port 5900, how can I access a specific container I want that I assume is identified within an output of a Jenkins job, which sends a selenium test script to one of the nodes on the grid?

I.e. if there's an issue with the test script and I see a container identifier, how can I access that specific container over VNC to see what's going on there?  Since there's a single host IP for multiple containers, they need to have different ports published externally vs 5900 to be distinguishable, but I don't see how this can be done in docker-compose/swarm.  Is this doable?

As an alternative, would that be any easier with Kubernetes rather than docker swarm? (I have not done much research on it yet)